# Book set in Australia shortly after the invention of teleportation

Tags: story-identification, teleportation

The book takes place in the near future somewhere in Sydney, Australia. It takes place after the recent invention of teleportation. It explores the social, political impact/consequences of  teleportation. You can't illegally teleport yourself into another country because they will block you also because they have their own separate networks. Roads are abandoned and most forms of transportation have been discarded. That's all I can remember

Comment: I don't think it's set in Australia, but Harry Harrison's *One Step From Earth* is one of the works that considered the implications.

Comment: @greg: Do you know when it was written? Nearest decade, at least?

Comment: my guess it was made not that long ago perhaps 1970 to present time frame.

Comment: Another novel where the social aspects of teleportation is Alfred Bester's *The Stars My Destination* (also known as *Tiger Tiger*, but it isn't set in Australia, and there is so much *else* going on that it doesn't really match the description given.

Comment: [Teleportation Wrecks Economy!](http://www.futureworld.org/PublicZone/MindBullets/MindBulletsDetails.aspx?MindBulletID=409)

Comment: There is a whole cluster of Niven stories (mostly from the 1970s) on the social and economic consequences of teleportation, but I don't recall any set in Australia.

Comment: @greg: Is the teleporting explicitly *called* "teleporting" in the story, or might they use some other term (jaunting, jumping, etc.)? Also, it's implied in your question but just to clarify - is the teleporting done through machinery, not some kind of mental ability?

Comment: I don't remember the details, but check F.M. Busby's wotks. Possibly Arrow from Earth?

Answer (score 8):

It might be Sean Williams' [*The Resurrected Man,*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1591023114) first published April 2005.

[image]

The author is Australian and at least some of the book is set in/around Sydney, specifically:

> Unit 142, NorthWest Isobloc, Faux Sydney, UNITED REPUBLICS OF
>   AUSTRALASIA

The book opens in the year 2069. Teleportation (D-Mat) is a relatively recent invention, which is still in the process of being integrated into society:

> Even in such countries as Quebec, where d-mat
>   travel was illegal for humans and livestock, access was not out of the
>   question. Not one government on Earth had outlawed mass-freighting by
>   d-mat, a testimony to the power of business over principles. Per
>   tonne, d-mat was both quicker and more efficient than any other rapid
>   transport currently available. It also promised clean and
>   environmentally-friendly manufacturing techniques that were already in
>   use off-Earth. A d-mat booth produced an object from data and basic
>   raw materials, but the data didn’t have to come from another booth; it
>   could come from its own internal memory, from a library, or a
>   catalogue of items that could be integrated at will. Economic analysts
>   were divided over whether d-mat mass-manufacturing would undermine or
>   enrich the global economy, but one thing was certain: the laws
>   permitting it would be passed one day, whether they were sound or
>   not.
>  ...
>      Fabian Schumacher, for
>   example. He was not the creator of d-mat (the head of the initial
>   research team and therefore nominal ‘inventor’, Nick Luhr, had been
>   dead for a decade), but he was the man who had put the process into
>   practise and continued to develop it in new and profitable ways.

Here's the book's description from the Amazon link above:

> Private detective Jonah McEwen is wanted for
>   murder. Someone has been killing women who resemble Marylin Blaylock,
>   his former colleague and ex-lover. The latest grisly discovery is
>   right on his doorstep. He is the obvious suspect.
>       The problem? He has been in a coma for three
>   years - a coma he has no memory of entering. And there's worse to
>   come.
>      Using matter transporter technology,
>   or "d-mat," a serial killer know only as the Twinmaker has been
>   brutally torturing and killing perfect facsimiles of his victims and
>   leaving the originals alive. As legal arguments rage about whether
>   this even constitutes murder, Jonah finds himself in the awkward
>   position of defending his innocence when his own exact copy might
>   actually be guilty.
>      Set in a time where
>   the lines between human and machine are increasingly blurred, The
>   Resurrected Man explores the future of terrorism, law enforcement, and
>   globe-spanning conspiracies. A perfect blend of suspense and science
>   fiction, the novel follows the complexities of Jonah and Marylin's
>   relationship and their quest to find the killer before he strikes
>   again, as well as unravelling the tensions between Jonah and his
>   father - a man who has been dead for three years but who might yet
>   hold the key to everything...
>      Nominated
>   for the Aurealis Award and winner of the Ditmar Award, The Resurrected
>   Man was hailed as a "tour de force" in Australia, the author's home
>   country, and described as "compulsively readable" by Locus.

Comment: this could be it ; but I remember reading the description onreddit so it's impossible to determine if this is it

Answer (score 0):

*One Step From Earth* was published in 1970, but I don't recall it having stories set in Australia, and if you were thinking of it you'd probably use the name "matter transmission".

So I'm guessing at *The Teleportation Reality* by Alexander Shoolman, published in 2011, ISBN 9780646570891 .